How can we constrain this set of equations to obtain the desired form?
How can we constrain this set of equations to obtain the desired form?
Solve[{(y0 - y)/(x0 - x) *-a/b == -1, 
  a*(x + x0)/2 + b*(y + y0)/2 + c == 0}, {x, y}]

get the result is:
{{x -> -((2 a c + a^2 x0 - b^2 x0 + 2 a b y0)/(a^2 + b^2)), 
  y -> -((2 b c + 2 a b x0 - a^2 y0 + b^2 y0)/(a^2 + b^2))}}

and how to get the result as follows:
{{x -> x0 - 2 a*(a  x0 + b  y0 + c)/(a^2 + b^2), 
  y -> y0 - 2  b*(a  x0 + b  y0 + c)/(a^2 + b^2)}}


$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

sol = Solve[
   {(y0 - y)/(x0 - x)*-a/b == -1, 
    a*(x + x0)/2 + b*(y + y0)/2 + c == 0},
   {x, y}][[1]]

(* {x -> -((2 a c + a^2 x0 - b^2 x0 + 2 a b y0)/(a^2 + b^2)), 
    y -> -((2 b c + 2 a b x0 - a^2 y0 + b^2 y0)/(a^2 + b^2))} *)

Thread[{x, y} -> ({x0, y0} + Simplify[({x, y} /. sol) - {x0, y0}])]

(* {x -> x0 - (2 a (c + a x0 + b y0))/(a^2 + b^2), 
    y -> y0 - (2 b (c + a x0 + b y0))/(a^2 + b^2)} *)

